# Rank of matrice: proof

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

I don't understand how to prove this property:

$n \in \mathbf{N}$, $A \in \mathbf{L(V)}$ with $X$ and $Y$ being two basis.
Then why is $rk(A) = rk(^{X}A^Y)$ true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** Notice that if $P$ is an invertible matrix then by the rank nullity theorem we see easily that
$$rk(PA)=rk(A)\quad;\quad rk(AP)=rk(A)$$
moreover notice that the matrix of a linear transformation $T$ relative to a basis $X$ and $Y$ is 
$$P^{-1}AQ$$
where $A$ is the matrix of $T$ relative to the standard basis and $P$ and $Q$ are the change basis from the standard basis to the basis $X$ and $Y$ respectively. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Because both P and Q transition matrices are invertible? We then apply this: $rk(PA)=rk(A);rk(AP)=rk(A)$. Is it like this?

Comment: Yes that's right.